# C# library for Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: c#, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to retrieve data from 'Amazon Product Advertising API', and I see that I need to sign my request, and then the response is an XML document which should be parsed. 
I wonder if there is any library which I can send my requests throught, and recieve the response back as an object.

If not, what should I do to convert those XML reponses to an object ? I've read about schemas, but where do I get those schemas from and where do I get from the defention for the response objects so I could define them my self.

Thanks alot!

Comment: AWS has an C# SDK that handles signing requests and parsing responses.  Have you looked into that? I haven't used product advertising but I'm sure it covers that API too

Comment: IMHO, XML DOM is an object.  Re-consider why you need the response in a POCO, you might find that the conversion to an intermediate object is just overhead.  You're likely a) inserting into a DB, b) presenting to HTML.  Both can be done easily with the data remaining in the XML, and not a POCO.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising/) package

```
PM> Install-Package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising
```

**Example:**

```
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication();
authentication.AccessKey = "accesskey";
authentication.SecretKey = "secretkey";

var client = new AmazonProductAdvertisingClient(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.DE);
//Search
var result = await client.SearchItemsAsync("canon eos");
//Lookup
var result = await client.GetItemsAsync("B00BYPW00I");
```

Comment: Hi, when I try to run above code, result always return null. I don't think that I have a problem with AccessKey and SecretKey but I cannot find what is the problem. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: check the response of this event `wrapper.ErrorReceived += (errorResonse) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorResonse.Error.Message); };`

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I've implemented the event but no error has returned. Is there anything I can check?

Comment: Please open a new question and post your code example

Comment: This is a useful post and I found that the nuget is being updated regularly

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that helps you sign requests AND process the responses by converting the XML into a relatively easy-to-use object. I've been using it for a few weeks now and wrote my own helper classes to really make querying the API fast and easy.

I wrote a demo console C# app where you can just plug in your Amazon credentials and start playing around here:
https://github.com/zoenberger/AmazonProductAdvertising

I also answered a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33617604/5543992